# Assumed pressure at tank outlet to derive Torriceli's law

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, bernoulli-equation

In the derivation of Torriceli's law it is assumed that the pressure at the tank hole is equal to atmospheric pressure.

I believe this is true when the water starts flowing through the hole but I do not understand why this should hold during the whole purge procedure.

Do you have ideas about the explanation? CFD calculations showing this behavior would be great.

Many thanks.